# Cannot access 'rainDrop' before Initialization

Tags: javascript, class, class-method

I am creating a Purple Rain Sim in Sublime Text using classes and object-oriented programming (which I am not used to). When I try to create a new object in the code below, my chrome console throws the error, "Cannot access 'rainDrop' before Initialization". 'rainDrop' is a class that creates raindrop objects. The rainDrop class is in the same .html file as the function, and the rainDrop class is coded before the function code.

This is the rainDrop class:

```
class rainDrop {
    constructor(x, yV, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = 0 - rainH;
        this.yV = yV;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

This function throws the error:

```
function create_rain_drop() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight);
    var yV = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var alpha = Math.random();
    var color = "rgb(148,0,211," + alpha + ")";
    new rainDrop(x, yV, color); // This line throws the error
// I don't believe the arguments in the function are throwing the error
}
```

Why is this error thrown?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: 1. Class names should start from a capital letter: `RainDrop`. 2. You cannot access the class _before_ its declaration has actually executed. In other words, if `create_rain_drop` is called _before_ the class declaration is executed, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 classes are not initialized in hoisting so if you use it in a function before it , it will throw error , so you can use function expression

```
class RainDrop {
    constructor(x, yV, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = 0 - rainH;
        this.yV = yV;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

const create_rain_drop = () =>{
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight);
    var yV = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var alpha = Math.random();
    var color = "rgb(148,0,211," + alpha + ")";
    new RainDrop(x, yV, color);
}
```

Comment: `create_rain_drop` can be declared above the class. Problem is _whether `RainDrop` class is `accessed` before it's declaration has actually executed_. If the function is _called after_ class declaration, there will be no error.

Comment: yes that can also be done , but if both of them are in different files , this is the better way

Comment: Your solution does not work for me when the class and function are in different files.